# bson module not found when running script in VSCode, works fine within the same conda environment in terminal

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pymongo, bson

I have created a new conda environment and installed `pymongo` from `conda-forge`. `pymongo` should install `bson` module as part of its installation and it does, as running my script from terminal works just fine. I checked the env path with `sys.executable` and set the same environment in VSCode. Then switched to VSCode terminal and called the script from there (just using `python script.py`), with the same environment activated. However, I got an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "src/script.py", line 2, in <module>
    import bson
ImportError: No module named bson
```

Any ideas what may be the source of the error? I feel like there might be some issue specific to `bson` module, as other packages seems to work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that the location where this module is installed is not in the python environment currently used by VS Code or the module file is damaged.

1. Please enter "`python --version`" or "`pip --version`" in the VS Code terminal to check the python environment used by the terminal, and the module will be installed here:

   [image]
2. In order to avoid the impact caused by the damage of the module file, we can find the location where the module was installed, delete the module folder, and then reinstall it: (`pip show module`)

   [image]

   [image]

run:

[image]